# pass url from one js page to another and extract exact value

Tags: javascript, chatbot, stock

how can i pass this `url="https://www.google.com/finance?q=tcs&ei=I7dtWaHxOJCuuATHoZaoCA"` from `store.js` page and getting exact stock price of tcs on my another `app.js` page using [chatbot](/questions/tagged/chatbot) and [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs).

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45186839/edit) and add your code (or the relevant parts) into it, because without that we cannot help. Please see [ask].

Comment: Could you please add some more explanation with what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: basically i am creating a bot with the help of LUIS and node.js which will give me stock price of any company i asked to bot. i want to pass google finance url in my store.js file and want to access it in my app.js file

Comment: Instead of implementing your own AI, you might want to check out [Stocks.js](https://github.com/wagenaartje/stocks.js)